# How to split string based on commas (',') without considering commas inside brackets('(' and ')')?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to split my string using python 3+ which is having commas. I don't want string to split based on commas inside brackets.

For example:-

```
 cstr = 'animal_tiger,(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",'')),1,3) AS INT))'
```

I want to split this into two string elements.

I tried splitting based on commas but it is taking inside commas as well.

```
 import re
 import csv 
 from StringIO import StringIO 
 cstr = 'animal_tiger,(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",'')),1,3) AS INT))'

 b = re.split(r',(?=")', cstr)
 print(b)

 c = re.split(''',(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)''', cstr)
 print(c)

 data = StringIO(cstr) 
 reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=';') 
 for row in reader: 
     print(row) 

 def split_with_commas_outside_of_quotes(string):
     arr = []
     start, flag = 0, False
     for pos, x in enumerate(string):
        if x == '(' and x == ')':
            flag= not(flag)
        if flag == False and x == ',':
            arr.append(string[start:pos])
            start = pos+1
    arr.append(string[start:pos])
    return arr

 print(split_with_commas_outside_of_quotes(cstr))

 print(cstr.replace('(','$')).replace(')','#').split(',')
```

Expected result is splitting of string into two different strings of list that is:-

```
 outputlist - ['animal_tiger','(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",'')),1,3) AS INT))']
```

remember the length of the list is 2.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.

Comment: Not exactly it's actually I am trying to fix split(',') of my code if I used split(',') it splits things inside () which is separate.

Comment: I hope you aware that impossible to correctly parse recursive patterns with regexp, right?

Comment: You're using Python3 but still saying `print row`. That's python2 syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Use this function:

```
def split_with_commas_outside_of_quotes(string):
    arr = []
    bracketCount = 0
    currentItem = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i == len(string)-1:
            currentItem += string[i]
            arr.append(currentItem)
        elif string[i] == "(":
            bracketCount += 1
            currentItem += string[i]
        elif string[i] == ")":
            bracketCount -= 1
            currentItem += string[i]
        elif bracketCount == 0 and string[i] == ",":
            arr.append(currentItem)
            currentItem = ""
        else:
            currentItem += string[i]
    return arr


cstr = 'animal_tiger,(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",'')),1,3) AS INT))'
print(split_with_commas_outside_of_quotes(cstr))
```

Output:

```
['animal_tiger', '(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",)),1,3) AS INT))']
```

Comment: range(len(string)) always starts from 0 so no need of explicitly declaring it.

Comment: Good point @Pradam . I just put it there to make the code more readable. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
data = """animal_tiger,(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",'')),1,3) AS INT))"""
data.split(',', 1)
>>> ['animal_tiger',
     '(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(replace(MAX(tigers_name),"Body Parts",\'\')),1,3) AS INT))']
```

Comment: not correct exactly what will happen if more than 1 (CAST) comes up?